# Disable Font Size for Authors using: add_theme_support('disable-custom-font-sizes');

Tags: block-editor

sorry if this is in the wrong place.
I want to take out the ability for authors to change the typography sizes in either Gutenberg or DIVI. We have a number of users that are unable to follow guidelines. For everything they do, they could just use the normal default. But I am unfamiliar with editing the themes in WP and am not sure where I would go about making this edit:
'add_theme_support('disable-custom-font-sizes');'

Also both DIVI and Gutenberg are available to them.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than messing with the theme code which might change should there be an update, why don't you disable the capability of the role in regards to your stated problem?

Comment: That would be great. But I do not see how? Would I need a plugin to edit the user roles?

Comment: Yeah sure. User role Editor plugin can do that.